# Database Migration from SQL Server 2008 R2 to 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to migrate all database at a time from SQL Server 2008 R2 to SQL Server 2014.

Single database can be migrated, restored and import successfully, but unable to attache database due to compatibility issue.

Comment: More details please. What kind of compatibility issues?

Comment: This question has very little to do with programming, more with dba activities. Voted to move to DBA.